# Django - duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my Django project i create an app to have additional information about registered users. So my model looks like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   class Meta:
      verbose_name_plural = u'User Profile'

   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/profile/avatar', blank=True, null=True)
   name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=20)
   surname = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
   phone = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=12)

   def __unicode__(self):
      return '%s' % self.user
```

Here is my registration form:

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
   username = forms.CharField(label=(u'Username'))
   email = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email'))
   password = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
   password1 = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

   class Meta:
      model = UserProfile
      exclude = ('user',)
      fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'password1')

   def clean_email(self):
      email = self.cleaned_data['email']
      try:
         User.objects.get(email=email)
      except User.DoesNotExist:
         return email
      raise forms.ValidationError("User with same email already exist, please change your email")
```

And here is view of my registration form:

```
def UserProfileRegistration(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()
            user_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
            user_profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
         else:
            return render(request, 'profiles/registration.html', {'form':form})
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
            context = {'form':form}
            return render (request, 'profiles/registration.html', context)
```

In user profile i create modelform where user can fill the fields from UserProfile model:

```
class ExtraProfileDataForm(ModelForm):
   name = forms.CharField(label=(u'Enter your name'))
   surname = forms.CharField(label=(u'Enter your surname'))
   phone = forms.CharField(label=(u'Enter your phone'))
   birthday = forms.DateField(label=(u'Enter birthday'))
   avatar = forms.ImageField(label=(u'Enter avatar'))

   class Meta:
      model = UserProfile
      fields = ('name', 'surname', 'phone', 'birthday', 'avatar')

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(ExtraProfileDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         for key in self.fields:
            self.fields[key].required = False
```

This is the view of the model form:

```
@login_required
def UserFullDataForm(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ExtraProfileDataForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            profile_user = request.user
            user_profile = UserProfile(user=profile_user)
            user_profile.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            user_profile.surname = form.cleaned_data['surname']
            user_profile.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            user_profile.birthday = form.cleaned_data['birthday']
            user_profile.avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']
            user_profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
          else:
            return render(request, 'profiles/extra_profile.html', {'form':form})
        else:
            form = ExtraProfileDataForm()
            context = {'form':form}
            return render (request, 'profiles/extra_profile.html', context)
```

But when I fill this form I got the error: 
`duplicate key value violates unique constraint "profiles_userprofile_user_id_key" DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(23) already exists.`
On the traceback i see that error in this line `user_profile.save()`. As i understand it happens because this script create new item with same id but not update it. What i have to change on my code to update existing item but not to create. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), which will return an existing item if it was found; otherwise create a new instance of the model.

In your user profile update view:

```
user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=profile.user)
```

Now, instead of creating a new profile each time - you are updating if a profile for that user already exists.